# how can get requests from wolfram (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried multiple solutions but i can't figure out what's wrong

my code:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ask(self, ctx, *, s: str):
        s.replace(' ', '+')
        req = requests.get("http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/result?appid=RPYQ54-Q3W9QJKWR9&i=" + s)
        author = ctx.message.author
        em = (author, req.text)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

my error:

```
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `em` variable is not a `discord.Embed` instance and it should be, if you want to create an embed:

```py
em = discord.Embed(title=str(ctx.author), description=req.text)
```

This is just an example, you can modify it as you wish, take a look at the docs

#### Reference:

- [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed)